# Power Point: SVGs to slides

Tags: svg, batch-processing, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a very simple task I want to accomplish: I have a folder with 25 SVGs created in Adobe Illustrator, and I want to create individual slides from these SVGs each containing one. I can insert SVGs into slides manually, that works and displays great. But I am looking for a way to do this in batch.

I found the functionality called `Insert -> Photo album`, but it does not let me insert SVGs. Instead it prompts me to convert them to a rasterized format, which I do not want. This seems surprising, as inserting individual SVGs works without rasterizing them as mentioned before.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? I am not looking forward to doing this manually for 25 slides.

Comment: Hi. Illustrator has no such functionality as far as I know, and not sure about PowerPoint. It's not really graphic design software, perhaps better to ask an MS Office expert. There's a stack exchange site called SuperUser which deals with lots of advanced MS Office questions.

Comment: For 25 slides it seems doing it manually will take half the time of searching for an automated solution, IF you can find one.

Comment: @Scott - yeah, question asked two hours ago, probably could have done it manually by now ;)

Comment: Automation is in general the way to go, but one must of course always consider if it's worth spending time on. Placing 25 images manually doesn't sound like anything worth automating. Could take perhaps 10-30 seconds each. So 5-15 minutes? It doesn't make this a bad question though. One could have 100s of images. But as mentioned by others, graphic designers won't normally use PowerPoint if they can avoid it.

Comment: Of course if I just have to do this once, doing it manually is fine, but it's not unlikely that I will encounter this use case again in the future. It appeared to me that this is kind of the base-usecase of creating a presentation: Having images that I want to put on slides. I am not really using Power Point often (hence my question), but I would have figured that this must be possible in a software with the core feature of creating slide shows. I know that Power Point is not really graphic design, but this stack exchange was the best match that Google came up with (sorry).